# Line breaks in textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea, line-breaks

```
<textarea><?php echo "Hello <br/> word!";?></textarea>
```

Output is:

Hello `<br/>` word!

My question is how to get line break,but not display `<br/>` ?

Comment: The `textarea` element is for user input. In rare cases, you might have a useful default value for it, but are you sure you are solving the right problem? Normally, when you insert text in a `textarea`, line breaks are significant, so there should be no reason to write `<br>` tags there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `\n` instead of `<br/>`.
But make sure you use `"` instead of `'`, like the example below.

```
<textarea><?php echo "Hello\nWorld!";?></textarea>
```

Comment: I outputing from database and my data is in variable.

Comment: Can you please explain why `'` won't work? is it something specific to `php`? (i'm not familiar with `php`)

Comment: It something specific to PHP.
@TomasLietuva the data in your database contains br's ?

Comment: @TomasLietuva so you need to replace `<br/>` occurrences in the raw data with `\n`. Not familiar with PHP myself, but surely such function exists.

Comment: `str_replace("<br/>", "\n", $the_data)`